# read more in wordpress doesn't take me to the full post

Tags: wordpress

hello every one i would like help from you my problem iswhen i'm using the_excerpt on wordpress and click on read more it doesn't give me the full article it give me the article page but with text cutted and read more again

he is my code for **content.php**

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
            if ( is_single() ) {
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            } else {
                the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
            }

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="post-details">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php the_author( ); ?>
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php the_date( ); ?>
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> <?php the_category(' ,' ); ?>
            <i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <?php the_tags( ); ?>
            <div class="post-comment-tags">
                <a href="<?php comments_link( ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><?php comments_number(0,1,'%' ); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- postdetails -->
        <?php
        endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
    <div class="post-image">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
    </div> <!-- postimage -->

    <?php } ?>

    <div class="post-extrait">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

screenshoot from my desktop
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SYId.jpg
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKjiI.jpg

Comment: I think you need to edit the Question to make your point clear it sound like the button not working .

Comment: from index the main page code inside `template-parts/content`

Comment: i found a solution i dont know if it's a good solution but in single.php and i have used the get_template _part and i created a content-single.php and  i have used the same code form content.php but i have replaced the_excerpt top the_content and now when i click on read more i have the full article

Comment: this is what I try to tell you ... in content.php use the_content and in main page use the_excerpt()

Comment: thank you my friend i i'm new in wordpress and stackoverflow as well hahaha but i had to learn wordpress because lot of clients ask for custom template and you have to learn how wordpress work to do that anyway thank you so much brother

Comment: no problem I and other here to help ... please dont forget to delete the data you add as answers and edit the Q and add them there better than your Q delete ... also when you get your answer make it as accepted to other will benefit form it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem in content page that it dont show the full content you are using

`<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`

you should use

`<?php the_content(); ?>`

Comment: the goal was to use the excerpt and when i click on read more i get the full post

Comment: I did not understand your Question your problem is not that the more button not working its that the page dont show full content

I edited my answer

Comment: exactly ... so you put `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` in the main page and the `<?php the_content(); ?>` in inner page ... what file you call in the main page ...

Comment: yes that it , as i said the goal was to click on read more and get the full article page you can click on the imagei posted it's a screenshot from my desktop

Comment: I understand so I told you in the main page whats the code the show one article

Comment: i use single.php to have one article

Comment: you can not use single.php in main page my friend